# What is an appropriate humidity for separating curds and whey?

Tags: cheese, kefir

Does anyone have guidelines for an appropriate humidity for separating curds and whey to make cheese (I'm doing it from kefir)? Specific temperatures are available, but sources I've seen just throw in "and humidity can affect the outcome too" without giving anything concrete.

I'm not sure if wetter is better, dryer is better, or, more likely, if there is a specific range.

Comment: Is the humidity that important? I thought the pH was the main thing.

Answer (score 1):

86 degrees Fahrenheit (with citric acid added before the heating process, if you want mozzarella/ricotta curds) or a culture added after this point (if using a culture give it 1 hour to start reacting and forming acids) rennet will need to be added in both cases. The temperature should be held at 72-77 degrees during the separation process. Humidity will not really have any effect on your cheese or kefir during the separation process.

Answer (score 0):

Humidity is not important in separating curds and whey, but you should make sure your house is not cold during the process.